# find lines (from a file) that contain a specified word

Tags: c++, c++11

I cannot figure out how to list out the lines that contain a specified word. I am provided a .txt file that contains lines of text.

So far I have come this far, but my code is outputting the amount of lines there are. Currently this is the solution that made sense in my head:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


void searchFile(istream& file, string& word) {

   string line;
   int lineCount = 0;

   while(getline(file, line)) {
     lineCount++;
     if (line.find(word)) {
       cout << lineCount;
     }
  }
}

int main() {
  ifstream infile("words.txt");
  string word = "test";
  searchFile(infile, word);
}
```

However, this code simply doesn't get the results I expect. 
The output should just simply state which lines have the specified word on them.

Comment: That doesn't output the index of the lines that contain the word, it outputs every single line, irrespective of containing the word.

Comment: Check what `std::string::find` returns, hint it isn't a bool

Comment: it prints out a crazy long number! quite strange. I am brand new to c++. How would one go about utilizing the find function in this case? If, of course, that is the approach to take.

Comment: `if (line.find(word) != std::string::npos)`  instead of  `if (line.find(word))`

Comment: this solution worked. Thank you!

Comment: @reeseb https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find "*Return value:
Position of the first character of the found substring **or [npos](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if no such substring is found**.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to sum up the solution from the comments. It is just about the `std::string`'s `find` member function. It doesn't return anything compatible with a boolean, it either return an index if found, or `std::string::npos` if not found, which is a special constant.

So calling it with traditional way `if (line.find(word))` is wrong, but instead, it should be checked this way:

```
if (line.find(word) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "Found the string at line: " << lineCount << "\n";
} else {
    // String not found (of course this else block could be omitted)
}
```